# date validation for textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
function IsValidDateTime(Day, Mn, Yr) {
    var DateVal = Day + "/" + Mn + "/" + Yr;
    var dt = new Date(DateVal);

    if (dt.getDate() != Day) {
        alert('Invalid Date');
        return (false);
    }
    else if (dt.getMonth() != Mn) {
        //this is for the purpose JavaScript starts the month from 0
        alert('Invalid Date');
        return (false);
    }
    else if (dt.getFullYear() != Yr) {
        alert('Invalid Date');
        return (false);
    }


    return (true);
}
```

Here it's working fine...i mean it cannot enter type of charaters from the keyboard,but if i delete the number.. then it shows an exption means date format is not correct..so...i want to enter date from calender..

Comment: you have also a typo : `dt.getDate() != Day`, i think it should be `dt.getDay() != Day` instead

Answer (score 1):

You could set readonly attribute for textbox:

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" readonly>
```

If by 'calender' you mean datepicker for example, see: http://jsfiddle.net/J4SER/

Comment: you are pressing backspace without focusing textbox which causing browser back event to trigger.

Comment: @SambaSiva ya i see but why you would like to press backspace?

Comment: nothing,when i press backspace or any button from the keyboard ,then it shows only " invalid date"..

Comment: How are you binding this method? Can't you provide relevant code?!

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 date type can assist you

`<input type="date">`

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent backspace and delete to work on textbox using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#date").datepicker();
    $("#date").on('keydown', function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if( key == 8 || key == 46 )
        return false;
  });
});
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J4SER/1/)